# Props in state For saving the value during input onChange

Tags: reactjs

https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/update-state-source-of-truth-sq57vt?file=%2Fsrc%2FTaskList.js Here is my example, I have a Todos List data, and the user can edit todo titles and save or cancel. Saving will change the data in the state, and in case of canceling, the title will remain the same. That's why I decided to have another state in my Task component:

```
function Task({ todo, onChangeTodo }) {
  const { title: initialTitle, id, done } = todo;
  const [isEditing, setIsEditing] = useState(false);
  const [title, setTitle] = useState(initialTitle);

  return (
    <div key={id}>
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        checked={done}
        name="done"
        onChange={(e) =>
          onChangeTodo({
            ...todo,
            done: e.target.checked,
          })
        }
      />

      {!isEditing ? (
        <>
          {initialTitle}
          <button
            onClick={() => {
              setIsEditing(true);
            }}
          >
            Edit
          </button>
        </>
      ) : (
        <>
          <input value={title} onChange={(e) => setTitle(e.target.value)} />
          <button
            onClick={() => {
              setIsEditing(false);
              onChangeTodo({
                ...todo,
                title,
              });
            }}
          >
            Save
          </button>
          <button
            onClick={() => {
              setIsEditing(false);
              setTitle(initialTitle);
            }}
          >
            Cancel
          </button>
        </>
      )}

      <button>Delete</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

For saving the value during input onChange, and initializing the value from the prop, in JSX, I use `initialTitle` to show the title (or I should use `editedTitle`), and also in the case of cancel, I use `setTitle(initialTitle);` - I am new to React.js; can you confirm if I am doing it correctly? Is it correct code?